# How to customize indicator-datetime to two line configuration?

Tags: gnome-panel, customization, clock, indicator

Before we used to be able to customize the gnome panel clock to two line style.  How could we do the same for indicator-datetime?

I understand there's dconf-editor from dconf-tools.  And by going to com.canonical.datetime it almost looks like the gconf-editor thing.

But entering

```
<sup><span rise="3000" font_desc="ubuntu 7.5" color="#DFD8C8" weight="normal">%a %d %b</span></sup>%n<sub><span font_desc="ubuntu 7.5" color="#DFD8C8" weight="bold">%I:%M %p</span></sub>
```

like before did not change a thing.

Also, just by changing clock by removing the date leaves huge empty spaces around the time, instead of creating more space.  It look horrible... how can i fix it?

EDIT: the extra spacing will only be fixed after log out.  Maybe it will work by killing gnome-panel, but i didn't try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the *time-format* key to `custom`. Have a look at this answer: [How to change the date format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43999/how-to-change-the-date-format/44025#44025)

When done, your time string seems to work fine.