# How to format datetime indicator in Unity's panel to show in two lines?

Tags: 11.04, unity, format, indicator

Is it possible to format datetime indicator in Unity3D to show in two lines?
I tried this:

[how-to-customize-indicator-datetime-to-two-line-configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44321/how-to-customize-indicator-datetime-to-two-line-configuration/44442#44442)

But that seems to work only when I run my Ubuntu 11.04 in classic mode. When using Ubuntu with Unity3D this command shows itself in the panel and nothing is formated. I figured out that I can make it to show in two lines with "%n" between date and time but then font is too big and indicator is not fully visible.

Any idea how to format or at least change the font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to do in the top panel, sorry.