# Is it possible to change Unity Panel fonts or font size?

Tags: unity, fonts, panel

Is it possible to change the font or at least the font *size* of text in Unity's indicator panel (for things like the clock and system indicator monitor) without changing Application Font size from the Appearance Preferences > Fonts settings? I'm using a small monitor and I'd like just a wee bit more space for the global applications menu.

Comment: @ Chris: Similar problem here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44781/how-to-format-datetime-indicator-in-unitys-panel-to-show-in-two-lines

Comment: @Wojciech How is that problem similar?

Answer (score 2):

This not the best way as it involves changing the size for **all** applications, but it's the only way I know.

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-appearance-properties`.
- Start the *Appearance Preferences* application from the search result.
- Go to the *Fonts* tab.
- Change the *Application Fonts* font settings.

Comment: I had already made the application fonts size as small as I was comfortable with, and was hoping for a panel-specific option to make that font one size smaller. I'll edit my question to reflect this. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Why on earth would you suggest alt+F2 and a long command? There's such a thing as the global menu.

Comment: @Chauncellor Feel free to post a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

### MyUnity

[image: Install via the software center]

In the *Fonts* section of MyUnity, you can set the System, Desktop, and Window  Title fonts to configure this.

[image: picture of the font section]

Comment: I'm getting no sources available on this?

Answer (score 0):

MyUnity isn't yet available for 12.10, so you might want to try gnome-tweak-tool if you're using that. gnome-tweak-tool of course will only work for changing system-wide default fonts.