# How do I change the font DPI settings?

Tags: gnome, 11.10, font-rendering, dpi

I installed Oneiric on a clean system, and found that the font tab is gone from the Appearance settings. This is a problem, because by default the text in Ubuntu is too large.

I changed the text from normal to small in the Universal Access settings, but then it was way too small.

[I also tried it this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59850/is-it-possible-to-change-font-dpi-in-11-04), but it doesn't appear to have any effect.

How can I get back the fine control and change my DPI from 96 to 90?

Comment: You might be able to start the settings program "by hand".

Comment: see also: http://askubuntu.com/q/45572

Comment: Since Ubuntu 14.04 there is a setting for the Screen DPI Scaling:
http://askubuntu.com/a/462023/294881

Comment: @BartVanHeukelom: Please explain, why do you want to change the FONT DPI and not the whole SCREEN DPI? as @user294881 said, this is possible now in `System Settings`->`"Displays"`->`"Scale for menu and title bars"` [Screenshot](http://askubuntu.com/a/485408/34298)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Gnome Tweak Tool

This is a common issue on the forums - the move to gnome3 has dumped many of the customisation features that were available in gnome2.

One GUI tool that exists in Software Center is `gnome-tweak-tool` - its a partial solution to allow you to customise some aspects of fonts.

The "Text scaling factor" is the option you are interested in - its unfortunate that it is a sliding bar so you will not be able to enter the actual DPI value.  Click on the sliding bar and use the left/right arrow keys to decrease/increase the font size.
[image]

### dconf-editor

Using `dconf-editor` which is available in the `dconf-tools` package allows you to set the "Text Scaling Factor" numerically i.e. changing the default value by fractions of numbers (1.2, 0.9 etc) changes the overall screen font size:

[image]

### Universal Access

If you just want to adjust the text size universally without need detail you can do this from the universal access tool:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't change the DPI, does it? It looks like it just adjusts font sizes to compensate.

Comment: Its the closest that I found - I haven't found anything closer to the old gnome-2 functionality.... unless you know of something? - doesnt appear to be anything in precise either :(

Comment: Appendix: Nowadays one can use Ubuntu Tweak.

Comment: Where in Ubuntu Tweak is that setting?

Comment: You can also adjust individual fonts with gnome-tweak-tool; notably you'll want to increase window title font which is unaffected by Text scaling factor.

Comment: This is not the best answer anymore. see 
@user294881 s Answer below

Comment: @rubo77 - they are two separate questions - one for the FONT DPI - and the other is for the SCREEN DPI.

Comment: But what for should you change the FONT DPI? this only causes a lot of problems, see: [Why are all HTML form elements huge with a system-wide font-scale factor 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23783899) - so I guess, 99,9% of all users want to change the SCREEN DPI

Comment: @rubo77 - if you want to discuss pop into the general chat-room - not via comments

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped me on setting GDM's DPI! (login to the GDM account via sudo or su > `export $(dbus-launch)` > `GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set`)

Answer (score 8):

If the key text-scaling-factor is missing from gconf-editor, check alternatively:

```
 gsettings list-schemas | grep org.gnome.desktop.interface
 gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.interface
 gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.9
```

(replace 0.9 with the desired value).

Comment: Too bad it's changing only scale factor. Not dpi

Comment: Why downvote? the first answer also doing the same thing

Comment: According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#GNOME , *“scaling-factor only allows whole numbers to be set. 1 = 100%, 2 = 200%, etc...”*

Answer (score 7):

Just open [**gconf-editor**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gconf-editor) [image: Install gconf-editor], navigate to the key `/desktop/gnome/font_rendering/dpi` and adjust to values you need.

[image]

Comment: gconf-editor is applicable to gnome shell only. If you want to change DPI for unity shell, use **dconf-editor** . (It comes with dconf-tools) The procedure is same as detailed above.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting `DisplaySize` in `xorg.conf`?

I added to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` a file with the size in mm, let's see how it works:

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "myMonitor"
  DisplaySize 223 125
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new option *Scale for menu and title bars* in **System Settings > Displays** in Ubuntu 14.04 as described [in this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/462023/294881), to set system-wide scaling factor.

Answer (score 0):

On Pop!_ OS (which also uses GNOME shell) I had to set scale to 200% for HiDPI to work. This may be equivalent on other systems. I've got a 24 inch monitor set to 3840x2160 and it system wide font-rendering was blurry (not HiDPI or Retina like) unless scale was 200%.