# How can I make PDFs appear life-size when displayed at 100%?

Tags: 11.10, resolution, monitor, evince, dpi

When I open a [letter size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_%28paper_size%29) PDF and then zoom to 100%, the page physically displayed on my monitor is smaller than a real letter size sheet of paper.

How can I make "100%" on the computer screen correspond with "100%" in real life?

### Details

[This message](http://osdir.com/ml/evince-list/2011-08/msg00024.html) suggests that I should be investigating the system-wide DPI settings for my monitor. `xdpyinfo` reports:

```
dimensions:    1024x768 pixels (271x203 millimeters)
resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

My monitor has a native [display resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution) of 1024x768 pixels and a diagonal [display size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_size) of 12.07 inches. [PX CALC](http://pxcalc.com/) returns the following information:

```
DPI: 106.05
Dot Pitch: 0.2395mm
Size: 9.66" × 7.24" (24.53cm × 18.39cm)
```

### What I've tried so far

Running `xrandr --dpi 106.05` successfully caused my PDF to appear actual size at 100%, but this effect was lost after rebooting.

To make the setting persistent I tried creating the following `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "ThinkPad X60 LCD"
    DisplaySize  245 183
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor    "ThinkPad X60 LCD"
EndSection
```

After re-logging in, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` contained

```
[  1167.824] (**) intel(0): Display dimensions: (245, 183) mm
[  1167.824] (**) intel(0): DPI set to (106, 106)
```

but `xdpyinfo` still reported

```
dimensions:    1024x768 pixels (271x203 millimeters)
resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

and "100%" still appeared too small.

Comment: Couldn't you just run `xrandr --dpi 106.05` as a script at startup?

Comment: On my computer, that `xrandr --dpi 125` call does not change anything in Okular or Xournal …

Answer (score 9, accepted):

xorg.conf doesn't even exist on new installs nowadays because of `xrandr`. Most drivers work fine with just xrandr and no xorg.conf (I think Nvidia is the exception). What you need is to have xrandr run at startup all the time. I documented on the Ubuntu Wiki [how to make xrandr commands run as soon as the GUI starts](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_commands_in_kdm.2BAC8-gdm_startup_scripts).  Just use the same xrandr command you already figured out.

For Unity users reading along, equivalent directions for lightdm are here: https://askubuntu.com/a/69501/1158

Comment: `xorg.conf` now exists in the form of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a very complicated question.

I can't tell you how to solve your problem, but I can tell you why it occurs.
Monitors have different pixel densities. A 1x1cm square on one monitor can contain a different amount of pixels that the same square on a different monitor.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density for more information on that.

Because of this, 100% zoom will give you differently sized documents on different monitors.

Given this context, this question is probably better phrased as "how can I change what 100% means in Evince?"
I don't know the answer to that. Sorry. I do hope my answer helps somewhat, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously on the right track, since you found that changing the DPI settings worked when you ran the `xrandr` command.

It used to be easy to change the DPI setting in Gnome itself, but apparently, Gnome 3 made this difficult.

You can check out this answered question on AskUbuntu for info about how to go about it in Gnome 3:

[How do I change the font DPI settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good answer on this [blog about Display Size, DPI, and Text Size… an interesting DIY](http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/display-size-dpi-and-text-size-an-interesting-diy/). He even includes a script to do the configuration automatically on startup. You will need to tweak it for your configuration though.