# How to change the screen DPI in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, unity, dpi

I want to change the DPI of the screen that is used in Ubuntu 11.10. How do I do this?

I don't just want to change the font size like in [How do I change the font DPI settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings), but I also want the icons to appear bigger.

Comment: Related: [How can I make PDFs appear life-size when displayed at 100%?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64480/how-can-i-make-pdfs-appear-life-size-when-displayed-at-100)

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: @BlueXrider - I don't know about the OP, but I'd like to know! Why is it flagged?

Comment: Still looking for the answer, yes.

Comment: In 14.04 there is a better solution now: [How to find and change the screen DPI?](http://askubuntu.com/a/462023/34298) `System Settings`->`"Displays"`->`"Scale for menu and title bars"` [Screenshot](http://askubuntu.com/a/485408/34298)

Comment: Changing the resolution of your monitor directly changes the DPI.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is exactly what you didn't want.

---

You can do this using the Gnome Tweak Tool, although you'll need to do some basic math :)

So first, install the `gnome-tweak-tool` package, or click [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gnome-tweak-tool/) install it.

Then go to the **Fonts** tab and change the **Text scaling factor**

[image: gnome-tweak-tool]

Then a little bit of math :)

[image: T(x)=x/96.0]

Comment: Will this only scale the _text_ or also the GUI widgets like buttons and minimize/maximize etc.?

Comment: Some GUI widgets are resized, especially the ones that depend on the font size. This includes buttons, titlebar (minimize, maximize), menu bar, etc. However, I've found that any widget that depends on the size of an icon, such as a toolbar, is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new app called **MyUnity** to change all sorts of settings for your desktop. More info at http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/myunity-is-a-small-simple-unity-tweaking-tool/

Comment: Thanks, but it only allows to change the font setting, not the screen DPI

Answer (score 0):

Changing the screen DPI seems to be the same than changing the screen resolution and I guess you know how you can do that. Reducing the resolution will show you everything *bigger*.

Now if you want to keep your screen resolution and have bigger icons then go to the nautilus preferences. Under **View/Icon View Defaults** you can set a higher zoom level.
Unfortunately there is only 100/150/200/400% to choose from.

There might be another way but unknown to me :-)