# How would Ubuntu work on an Apple retina display?

Tags: display, resolution, macbook-pro

Apple has announced a laptop with "retina display" = [2880x1800 pixels](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/features/) resolution on 15 inches.
If one were to load Ubuntu on such a machine, it would probably be unreadably micro-texted as long as Ubuntu treats one pixel as one pixel.

Would it be possible to adjust Ubuntu to use such a display in a meaningful way? Difficult? Easy?

Comment: Might be of interest: [How to change the screen DPI in 11.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66224/how-to-change-the-screen-dpi-in-11-10) and [How can I make PDFs appear life-size when displayed at 100%?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66224/how-to-change-the-screen-dpi-in-11-10). No great answers on those though.

Comment: A temp solution coudld be to set your screen to 1440x900? Might be better for gaming as well.

Comment: Has anybody tried it?

Comment: @Smatik - you should submit that as an answer - I think that for now it'll be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you adjust the DPI settings for the fonts. You have several options:

1. Using `gnome-tweak-tool`: Advanced settings > Fonts > Text scaling factor
2. Using `dconf-editor`: org > gnome > desktop > interface > text-scaling-factor

Comment: Will this only scale the _text_ or also the GUI widgets like buttons, borders, minimize/maximize, status icons in the toolbar, etc.? Will the cursor also be scaled or remain miniaturized?

Comment: You can try it on your actual system.

Comment: I tried this with a 1600x900 laptop before, in 11.04 i think, and the results were not impressive - a lot of widgets/screen features seem to have fixed pixel size and some apps didn't respect the font settings anyway (and some only for parts of their UI, which was quite strange). Love to hear if someone has experiences with a more recent Ubuntu..

Answer (score 0):

Sample of resolution change through command line

```
/usr/bin/xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1200
```

Simply run

```
xrandr
```

to list all available resolution