# How to change desktop font size

Tags: 11.10, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the font DPI settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings)

How to change desktop font size?

I tried compiz-settings-manager and gnome-tweak-tool

Comment: not duplicate.
i want change desktop(only) font.

Comment: You are quite right. I could change all my font settings save the font under the icons on my desktop. I found this solution: put this command in the terminal (change the font and size to whatever you wish): gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font "Ubuntu 9"

Comment: THANK YOU ALOT

You can edit this grafically with gconf-editor

with gconf-editor, see "desktop_font" value for the following key:
/apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_font

[URL=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/hopk.png/][IMG]http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/6861/hopk.th.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/6861/hopk.png

Comment: Yes, and I just found you can do the same with dconf here: /org/gnome/nautilus/desktop, under font. It would be nice if this question were reopened so the solution could be seen more easily!

Comment: In 14.04 there is a better solution now than changing the fonts:  `System Settings`->`"Displays"`->`"Scale for menu and title bars"` [Screenshot](http://askubuntu.com/a/485408/34298)