# Scale title bars and menu in Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, titlebar

I've installed gnome in my new 14.04 (not the Ubuntu-Gnome distribution). I've noticed the title bars are huge though, and I would like to change.

The things is that this solution from [here](http://www.itworld.com/software/415502/scale-title-bars-and-menu-ubuntu-1404) is not available for me:

> 1. Go to System Settings.
> 2. Go to Displays.
> 3. Go to "Scale for menu and title bars."
> 4. Drag the slider to your preferred size.

Is there somewhere else I could change this? I looked in gnome-tweak-tool and also ubuntu-tweak-tool without success.

[image: This is my display windows and, as you can see, there is no scale option.]
This is my display windows and, as you can see, there is no scale option.

Comment: Why would you need another option to change this? Are you not satisfied? Or **Why is it not available for you?

Answer (score 7):

You can find out where the setting is changed if you open a terminal:

```
gsettings list-recursively>/tmp/before
echo 'Now unity-control-center should open. Please change the scaling in "Displays" and close.'
unity-control-center
gsettings list-recursively>/tmp/after
diff /tmp/before /tmp/after |grep '[>|<]'
```

You find out, that these settings were changed (changing from scaling 1.0 to 2.0):

```
< org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor uint32 1
> org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor uint32 2
< com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 8}
> com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 16}
```

Or changing from 1.0 to 1.5 there is changed the `text-scaling-factor` instead, because `scale-factor` is integer:

```
< org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0
> org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.5
< org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 24
> org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 36
< com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 8}
> com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 12}
```

from 1.5 to 2.0:

```
< org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor uint32 1
> org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor uint32 2
< org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.5
> org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0
< org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 36
> org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 24
< com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 12}
> com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 16}
```

Those settings can be edited by hand with `dconf-editor`

This is very interesting in context with the `about:config` variable in [Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487032/adjust-firefox-and-thunderbird-to-a-high-dpi-touchscreen-display-retina/487033#487033): `devPixelsPerPx` that changes the size inside Firefox (see also: [Why are all HTML form elements huge with a system-wide font-scale factor 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783899/))

Also, you can write a script to change the scale factor with these settings like `/usr/local/bin/setscalefactor`:

```
if [ "$1" == "1" ]; then
  # set scaling to x1.0
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
  gsettings set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor "{'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 8}"
else
  # set scaling to x2.0
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
  gsettings set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor "{'HDMI1': 8, 'eDP1': 16}"
fi
```

---

additionally:

This doesn't scale the title bars and menu, but there is also [unity-tweak-tool](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool), where you can change the overall font-scaling.

Maybe that is an alternative you could use apart from the [Scaling Support in System Settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/485408/34298)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have reputation to comment, so I just want to say thanks to [rubo77](https://askubuntu.com/users/34298/rubo77), because his answer does not only solves the problem well, but adds a useful piece of code to scope into `gsettings`.

I would also like to contribute some more...

On my HP ProBook 5320m, the output of his script when moving slider from 0.875 to 1 is:

```
< org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 0.875
> org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0
< org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 21
> org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 24
< com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'default': 8, 'VGA1': 6, 'LVDS1': 7}
> com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'default': 8, 'VGA1': 6, 'LVDS1': 8}
```

but I've found out, that it is enough to change the value in the last line standing for `com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor LDVS1` parameter. Obviously this is always 8 times the real scale factor and the `cursor-size` and `text-scaling-factor` is changing along with it accordingly (for scaling >2 it changes also `< org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor uint32` from 1 to 2 or higher, but the described procedure still works the same).

This

```
function gnsc {
    b=$(echo "scale=0; $1*8" | bc) 
    b=${b%.*} 
    gsettings set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor "{'default': 8, 'VGA1': 6, 'LVDS1': $b}" 
}
```

is what I put in my `.bashrc` to change the scaling flawlessly within a terminal, eg. typing `gnsc 0.875`, even 
though I don't have that problem of missing slider from the initial question.

This is my first post on [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/) ever, so I hope someone will find it useful! :)