# How to reset scale menu size back to default?

Tags: 14.04, resize, reset, menu-bar

Accidentally I set the scale menu size to 6. This resulted to both menu and bar occupy half of my screen. I tried to restore it but the window of the settings cannot be re sized, so, it's not possible to see where this option is and reset it.

Is there any way to change it, even from command line?

In the system I already have other user accounts with administration rights and I can use them to gain access the user account that has this problem, if necessary.

System information: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> and move the windows by dragging it while holding <kbd>ALT</kbd>, this will allow you to move the windows out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks. Did that but nothing.

Comment: I moved it out of bounds but it didn't move enough so as to be able to see the corresponding option and change it. Looking around, I found the gsettings command and tried to reset the whole schema org.gnome.desktop.interface from command line in terminal (the only program I can barely use) but with no luck. The output of the command seemed that the command executed successfully but when I rebooted no reset had occured. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: this link might be of a help --- http://askubuntu.com/questions/471425/scale-title-bars-and-menu-in-ubuntu-14-04-with-gnome

Comment: I came across this link yesterday and that's how I learned and checked the -- gsettings -- command. What I noticed is that, I checked the resolution with the -- xrandr -- command and the resolution was 1920x1080, as it should. So thought that something is going on with the font used.

Comment: I used the -- dconf editor -- on another account and compared the settings of both accounts. I found a difference in com.ubuntu.User-Interface schema where the scale factor for HDMI1 was 8 and for LVDS1 was 48; whilst the other account had both scale factors 8. I tried to change it but with no luck. In the terminal I was changing and it seemed it worked but once I was logging out and logging in again the change I made dissapeared. I tried to execute the command from console in a console but still with no luck. Checked the configuration for any potential changes and noticed that ...

Comment: ... the file /home/user/.config/monitors.xml had more configurations declared but probably because this user was used to connect laptop with a tv.

Comment: However, I came across a link (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2080752) which describes how to restore a corrupted user account, since such seems to be my case. I followed the steps and worked for me so, it seems to be closed to me, even though I have no idea what was the corruption.