# How to scale title bars and menu in Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04 with the terminal only

Tags: 14.04, command-line, scale-mode

To keep the story short: Out of curiosity I wanted to know how the scale option would look like with value 5.something. Now I'm stuck with a highly oversized system where I can't change anything (because the window, which seems to be fixed in size) is too large so that I could change the scale value.
I get to the window where I can change the screen options, but that window is too large so that I can see the or reach the scale function or even save it.

I have already tried to reset the value using ubuntu on my laptop and counting how many times I have to press the Tab-button and where to change things etc. Since the terminal works, I need a way to reset the scale value to 1 using the terminal. Any other idea that works is fine for me as well.

I'm using the 14.04.1 version.

Answer (score 14):

In a terminal, run:

```
dconf reset /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor
```

Comment: +1 This also works with 16.04

Answer (score 6):

It took me some time but it is working again. The solution:

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal
- Install *dconf editor* by running

  ```
  sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
  ```
- Open *dconf-editor*

  ```
  dconf-editor
  ```
- Navigate to ***com→ubuntu→user-interface***
- Change or reset the *scale-factor** to, for example, 10 or 20 (depends on your system)

I know that the last step can be hard since you may don't see that much if you have a septup like mine (a small slit where you could only see like a few pixel of the text). On my system it's the only value in there though.

Sometimes the desktop can be a little bit wonky and flicker around so you better restart your system.

Refer [rubo77's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/486611/326897) on [Scale title bars and menu in Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471425) for more.

Comment: There's like 6 different values in there. Setting them **all** to 10 seems to have worked; I think one for each monitor (probably includes my old monitors too).