# How can I reset my display settings through terminal?

Tags: command-line, display, monitor, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 15.10. I accidentally changed the size of the interface to maximum. Now my folders and windows are too large and don't fully fit the screen so I cannot revert the effect. Is there any way to reset the display settings to default so this can revert to normal?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Removing `~/.config/monitors.xml` should do it:

- Open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `rm ~/.config/monitors.xml` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- immediately log out and back in. It should be reverted now

#### Alternatively

If you know what resolution your screen supports (e.g. `1440x900`), you can run the command:

```
xrandr -s 1440x900
```

to at least temporarily set a workable solution, then subsequently change settings from GUI.

Comment: it did not work.

Comment: uhd. It was the highest in the settings and it is already set at that resoloution. i think 3840x2160

Comment: Hi @alexanast just (re) tested it. Did you forget to log out/in? it works really.  Local monitor settings are stored in `~/.config/monitors.xml`. There is no way these settings are remembered if you remove the file and immediately log out, unless you must have done something exotic.

Comment: login screen fixed but desktop enviroment didnt. Restarting to check.        edit It did not.

Comment: @alexanast curious to what you did to change the settings?

Comment: well i guess i will mark this as correct since it should work. I fixed it through settings by going in blind using tab so no problem. Thanks for the soloution and you patience

Comment: also works if you know the resolution you want, edit the monitors.xml file and set the resolution to your desired value

Comment: A quick and effective way to restart the GUI (both Xorg and Wayland) in case of problems like this is to use the `Ctrl-Alt-Backspace` shortcut. You could remove `monitors.xml` and restart GUI right away using this shortcut. Unfortunately is disabled by default. You need to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and answer yes when prompted to enable this shortcut.

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 and ~/.config/monitors.xml does not exist on my machine, what could be some possible alternate locations for this file?

Comment: I had to restart the computer in order to have it work, but basically removing the `monitors.xml` did the trick.

Comment: if you ended up in the recovery mode with root access the file will not be under `~`, but under `/home/yourusername` instead

Comment: I was having some bizarre dual monitor behaviors and this removal fixed it, many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem to you but I found the solution here
[How to scale title bars and menu in Ubuntu 14.04 with the terminal only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582566/how-to-scale-title-bars-and-menu-in-ubuntu-14-04-with-the-terminal-only)

```
dconf reset /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor
```

This changes the "scale for menu and title bars" to default.

Comment: This worked for ubuntu 16.04 atleast

Comment: Also you can use `dconf-editor`, go to that path, _Set to default_.

Comment: it 's really good answer..thank

Comment: you rescue me ! this works for ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to this, since this is the first thread that appeared for me:
My solution to reset the display was to use:

```
xrandr --listactivemonitors
```

Comment: But this doesn't *reset* anything?

Comment: If you unplug an external monitor and display doesn't reset, running this will reset the monitor config.

Answer (score 0):

In KDE all monitors are scaled together in ~/.config/kwinrc

```
[Effect-zoom]
InitialZoom=1.23
```

Answer (score -1):

Just rebooting can fix it, but it depends on what caused the change.

Before you fiddle with settings, reboot and see if the resolution reverts to the correct setting.