# Primary monitor only works when secondary is connected

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have Kubuntu 14.05.5 running on a Sony Vaio notebook.

When no external monitor is connected, the internal monitor (primary display) is not showing anything. 
When I connect an external VGA monitor, the internal one works as specified in the "Display" settings. 
(In the Display settings, the internal monitor is set as primary display, the external display is set to inactive.)

Similarly, `xrandr -q` reports 2 monitors to be connected when both are connected, and the internal one being primary.

When I run `xrandr -q` while the external monitor is disconnected, only the internal one is recognized (not specified to be primary).

I tried `xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary`, but that didn't change anything.

It is my friend's computer. They reported that the problem first occurred after installing updates while an external monitor was connected.

What to do?

Comment: When you first boot your BIOS shows up on your laptop screen and external is blank right? When grub menu appears your laptop screen has the menu and the external screen is blank right?

Comment: right. it's something on the user level. i've created a new user, no display anomalities there.

Comment: So, I think your problem is easy to be solved. Just [rename or delete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749333/how-can-i-reset-my-display-settings-through-terminal) `~/.config/monitors.xml` before enter your account session (at tty session) and redo your monitor settings after entering it.

Comment: `~/.config/monitors.xml` does not exist.