# Accidental zoom in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. Just a few hours ago, I had logged out my PC. But in my absence, my little sister pressed some key combinations and eventually, the whole screen got magnified. I'm not able to figure out which key combination was that.

I'm not able to do my routine work.

I tried CompizConfig but it didn't worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try "Super Alt -" for zooming?

Comment: Yah, already tried that. And the thing is, it is not just the desktop, but the whole screen is magnified.

Comment: Does this link help any? https://askubuntu.com/questions/749333/how-can-i-reset-my-display-settings-through-terminal

Comment: Ok, I got that. Actually I was using "-" key of numpad, but when I pressed "-" key below the function keys (i.e. the hyphen-minus key), it worked.
Thanks!! @Rinzwind

Comment: good, would be a bit overkill to have to reinstall ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind This is the second little brother / little sister problem you've commented to in the last 10 minutes. It must be International Sunday Little Sibling Day.

Comment: cat related computer problems are just as bad :D