# Ubuntu screen going black after login

Tags: 22.10

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 on a Dell laptop. I recently tried playing with the display settings to save battery life. I decreased the frame rate to 48 Hz and reduced the screen resolution to the minimum value. But as soon as clicked apply, my screen went black. How can I undo this change and bring back the display to the default state? I tried rebooting the system and the boot screen and login pages are being displayed as before, but as soon as I login the screen goes black.

I'm able to login to the 'tty' mode, can someone suggest the commands I should run to change the display settings to the default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/749336/1048397). Deleting the `~/.config/monitors.xml`  file fixed the problem.