# Font or windows scaling changed between 15.10 and 16.04

Tags: fonts, scaling

After update from 15.10 to 16.04 it seems that some scaling was changed, so fonts in 16.04 looks smaller (see attached screenshots). Do you know which settings is responsible for that?

**15.10**
[image]

**16.04**
[image]

Comment: i think you changed geany font size if it a general problem may ubuntu font size check this link to adjust  http://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size

Comment: Fonts are the same (DejaVuSansMono 10) - generally Geany use monospace 10. Same problem is also visible in Eclipse. I tried many options in fonts area, and none helped...

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this by downgrading libfreetype6:

1. Download [i386](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freetype/2.5.2-4ubuntu2/+build/7893588) and [amd64](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freetype/2.5.2-4ubuntu2/+build/7893585) lib packages for wily (links in the bottom of a page `libfreetype6_2.5.2-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb (304.7 KiB)`).
2. Open terminal, run `sudo dpkg -i libfree*`
3. Prevent auto-upgrade `sudo apt-mark hold libfreetype6`

As another workaround you may set monospace font in `~/.fonts.conf`:

```xml
<fontconfig>
  <match target="pattern">
    <test qual="any" name="family">
      <string>monospace</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign">
      <string>Liberation Mono</string>
    </edit>
    <edit name="pixelsize" mode="assign">
        <times><name>pixelsize</name>, <double>1.08</double></times>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: Add +1 ("Does this bug affect you?") to this bug, please https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/freetype/+bug/1613450

Answer (score 0):

Control in Settings->Displays that the scaling factor is the same that in 15.10, otherwise you can change it with the selector (I use it to enlarge all beacuse i have 4K monitor)

Comment: I can not see such setting in my system. I tried playing with dconf-editor and still no success. In my opinion some scaling value has changed, but I do no know which.

Comment: My displays settings is like [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rK9ep.png) . Anyway in [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/582566/how-to-scale-title-bars-and-menu-in-ubuntu-14-04-with-the-terminal-only) you can find how to use dconf

Comment: Thanks, I do not have this setting, changing it from dconf also does not change anything. I run live ubuntu 16.04 and the same issue is visible.

Comment: You can try with this command "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor <newnumberhere>" but I don't know if it works with lastest versions of Ubuntu

Comment: Yes, it is working, I changed it to 1.06 and looks much better. I am still interested what happened that I had this problem.  text-scaling-factor has the same value in 15.10 and 16.04 so it is not the root cause... Also it make those apps that looked good looks now ugly...

Comment: It may be a graphics driver issue, but i'm not sure. Anyway I have a lot of graphics issues too on 16.04 and a problem with the fan when I use nVidia driver