# How to set different scaling on multiple monitors?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

I have a notebook with a resolution of 3200x1800, running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with kernel 4.0.0-040000-generic. Unitys scaling function works great to magnify the menus, titlebar and applications. Now I would like to connect an external monitor via displayport with a resolution of 1920x1080.

Due to the high scaling, the menus on this monitor are extremely huge. The gui settings seem to allow to set different values for the magnification of each monitor. Unfortunately this option seems to work incorrectly. For example: When I chose the internal monitor and set the magnification for it, the menus and application on the external monitor are very big. Then I chose the external monitor in the gui settings and decrease the magnification. This only results in a smaller launcher and title bar. The menus and applications are as big as before.

I tried to find out where the settings are taken like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471425/scale-title-bars-and-menu-in-ubuntu-14-04-with-gnome). When changing the value for the external monitor, the following seems to happen:

```
user@computer:~$ diff /tmp/before /tmp/after |grep '[>|<]'
< com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'eDP1': 13, 'HDMI1': 8}
> com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'eDP1': 13, 'HDMI1': 6}
```

On the other hand, when changing the magnification of the internal monitor, this is the result:

```
< org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.625
> org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0
< org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 39
> org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 24
< com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'HDMI1': 7, 'eDP1': 13}
> com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor {'HDMI1': 7, 'eDP1': 8}
```

As you can see, only `com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor` is set for the external monitor, which appears to be the size of the launcher and titlebar.

It this a bug or can somebody please explain me how to set the size of the titlebar, applications *AND* menus separately for each monitor?

** Note (23.12.15): **
I created the following bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1528319

**If anybody else is affected by this bug as well, please note it at the bug report page to increase its priority.**

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-two-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screen. There are interesting suggestions there. I agree with you this is a bug in Unity, not solved in 15.10.

Comment: Confirming still a problem in 16 lts.