# How to enable sub pixel hinting?

Tags: display, fonts

Fonts are displayed a little bit blurry on my TFT screen. I fixed this in previous Ubuntu releases by enabling sub pixel hinting in the font settings. But now I can't find any font settings dialog in Unity. How can I enable sub pixel hinting or change the font family or font size? Where is all this stuff?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Welcome to the new no-user-serviceable-parts-inside Ubuntu/Gnome.

Install gnome-tweak-tool (`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`) and run it (it's called "Advanced Settings"). The font settings are in the Fonts tab.

- [How do I change the font DPI settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings)

Answer (score 17):

The easy answer is "`apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`", but that has the downside of pulling in `gnome-shell` and lots of associated packages.

You can do it on the command line using gsettings. For example:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings hinting
'slight'
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings hinting full
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings hinting
'full'
```

Valid values [appear to be](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-tweak-tool/tree/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_font.py) "none", "slight", "medium", "full".

You can also configure the antialiasing settings in a similar way.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings antialiasing
'rgba'
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings antialiasing none
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings antialiasing
'none'
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings antialiasing grayscale
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings antialiasing
'grayscale'
```