# Ubuntu 18.10: blurry fonts

Tags: fonts

Is there any way to make Ubuntu fonts sharper and less blurry, like in Windows?

The attached screenshot shows the same page in Firefox in Windows and Ubuntu and Ubuntu one looks much more blurred and unclear (at least, for me).

Everything else works great in Ubuntu and I am very pleased with it, the only issue I have is the font and/or rendering.

I am currently using default Firefox fonts in both systems and Segoe UI as a default font in Ubuntu.

Could you please what can I do to make Ubuntu fonts look like Windows (the same sharpness, rendering, etc)? Thanks.

[image: Fonts Ubuntu vs Windows]

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu uses Gnome there is no tool installed that could help you render the fonts correctly. 
Check this [answer] ([How to enable sub pixel hinting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70606/how-to-enable-sub-pixel-hinting)), it might solve your problem.