# How to fix blurred desktop on Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: nvidia, gnome

After Ubuntu upgrade to 20.10, I suffer from the bug where my desktop gets all blurry, except the things I select with the cursor (sometimes it's enough to just hover the mouse).

For example, this is how I see the [How to enable sub pixel hinting question & answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70606/how-to-enable-sub-pixel-hinting):

---

[image: What I see]

---

Note that I've tried to change antialiasing & hinting to all possible combinations via gsettings, but none of them helped.

After I start the system, everything is okay up until some point, where the whole system freezes for couple of seconds, all windows gets refreshed, the desktop background flashes and then, all graphics gets blurry. Not just text, even icons and images are blurred.

---

I've search dmesg and I see only two distinct errors:

```
[    5.138737] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    5.139272] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    5.139877] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
[    5.140370] ucsi_ccg: probe of 0-0008 failed with error -110
```

```
[ 3422.483442] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [VRTC] (00000000b7abfcfe) [SystemCMOS] (20200528/evregion-127)
[ 3422.483456] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20200528/exfldio-261)
[ 3422.483474] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q9A]
[ 3422.483477] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q9A]
[ 3422.483482] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q9A due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20200528/psparse-529)
```

---

But I've found something rather interesting in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 26 23:06:02 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: Window manager warning: MetaSyncRing: Sync object is not ready -- were events handled properly?
Oct 26 23:06:09 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (WW) NVIDIA: Wait for channel idle timed out.
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: Window manager warning: META_CURRENT_TIME used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: Object Meta.BackgroundActor (0x555e4a6b4e00), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: == Stack trace for context 0x555e4747e220 ==
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: #0   7ffcb4ac9580 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GObject.js:574 (2924ac7a4060 @ 25)
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: #1   555e4870e928 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:212 (1f25c3497880 @ 85)
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: #2   555e4870e8a0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:148 (1f25c34979c0 @ 12)
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: #3   555e4870e818 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:251 (2924ac7bed30 @ 12)
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: JS ERROR: TypeError: actor.get_meta_window() is null#012_destroyWindowDone@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1616:32#012onStopped@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1586:39#012_makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:82:22#012_easeActor/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:165:64#012_initializeUI/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:251:16
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous gnome-shell[4223]: JS ERROR: TypeError: actor.get_meta_window() is null#012_destroyWindowDone@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1616:32#012onStopped@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:1586:39#012_makeEaseCallback/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:82:22#012_easeActor/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/environment.js:165:64#012_initializeUI/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:251:16
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Oct 26 23:06:19 anonymous /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4084]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

- does this mean I would fix it by reverting to 20.04 ? It seems like some breaking changes were introduced to the gnome window manager.

My `nvidia-smi` output:

```
# nvidia-smi 
Mon Oct 26 23:49:11 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 207...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     2W /  N/A |    311MiB /  7982MiB |     10%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

---

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Experimentally, I've found out that apart from restarting whole system, it's enough to just restart the `systemd-login.service` (which obviously logs you out):

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart systemd-login.service
```

Since it's almost equivalent to system restart, I do not consider this a proper remedy.

---

It happened again, so I've restarted the `gdm.service` (it worked, but it also logged me out, so it's also not a good solution):

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm.service
```

---

Here it came again, so I've logged-out and back in, which worked, but I also lost my work session, so it's also not a good solution.

---

After it happened again, I've tried suspending the system, but that did not solve the blurry desktop.

---

When it happened again, I've tried hibernating the system as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate). But I couldn't make it work.

---

However, I've found out that the bug occurs only when I have launched a Mattermost desktop application, I click it in the toolbar and select a chat, which should focus the window and switch the chat to the selected, yet the blurred desktop bug happens instead.

- since I've stopped using that toolbar icon, I haven't suffered from this bug anymore

Answer (score 0):

if you have gnome extensions disable them all then log-out and then you log in again and re-enable every extension 1 by 1.

Comment: Well, I had only a single one gnome extensions enabled (and it was [Desktop Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/)), I've disabled it and re-logged in, now I'll see if it happens again.

Comment: I've disabled all the gnome extensions, but it happened again, so it's not a problem of an extension :/

Comment: i'd say reinstalling the drivers or reinstalling ubuntu then