# Need to manually change scaling when remote desktop connecting to high resolution display

Tags: fonts, remote-desktop, rdp, dpi, scaling

I have a Windows 8.1 desktop machine with a 27" QHD monitor. Under Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display, I have set "Change the size of all items" to medium (recommended) so I can comfortably read the font on my QHD screen.

I then want to remote desktop from my linux notebook with a 15" FHD screen, so I set the remote desktop resolution to 1920x1080 in Remmina and connect to the server. The problem is the font and titlebars are huge.
If I go into the display settings in my remote desktop session, the "Change the size of all items" setting is on the lowest (Smallest) setting and is grayed out regardless. I can click on "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays and set the scaling to 100%. After logging out and back into my remote desktop session the font and title bars are all scaled nicely to a usable size, which is great! Then I log back into my desktop machine directly and the font is minuscule, so I need to increase the scaling settings on my desktop again.

I have tried searching for other people with the same problem and my search terms are either bad or no one else has the same problem or setup, which I find hard to believe.

I would really like to find a good fix so I don't need to use a clumsy workaround of changing the DPI every time I log in from a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

gconf-editor should allow you to set adjust the font DPI, effectively scaling it dynamically. [See this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/59856/415700)

[image: gconf-editor]

Comment: I'm not really sure that this is the answer. The font dpi is fine in my native gnome session. I just need it adjusted in my remote desktop session.