# How to change font display size?

Tags: gnome, gui

Last week, fonts in Ubuntu 20.04 have grown a lot bigger. How do I revert them to the old size? I can't find desktop icon font size in settings or tweak tool.

Comment: Are you sure that your screen resolution or scaling hasn't changed?

Comment: I suppose that your issue was due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440). A fix has been committed and you will get it (if you haven't already) through an update.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you can try this out to change font size on ubuntu 20.04:**

1. **Option One:**

   - open settings.
   - go to universal access.
   - check if Large Text is on - if it is, turn it off.
2. **Option Two:**

   - use gnome tweaks.
   - use `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` to install the tool.
   - after installation open the app.
   - then change the scaling factor value to 1.0 (wich is the default value).
3. **Option Three:**

   - using terminal to increase or decrease text size.
   - `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor (value)`  - value 1 its the default value.
   - `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor` - to reset the value to his default size.
   - **this link found helpful to solve the problem** [How do I change the font DPI settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings) (added after edit).

Comment: @Christine - hey there, does my answer help out with solving the problem?

Comment: I had already checked 1 and 2. 3 does the same as 2, right?. I am wondering how Ubuntu changed this by itself.

Comment: well it just worked for me twice on option 2 and 3, i dont know what to say, i cant find an option to add a video or image to the comment here, it does not posting any output after executing the commands? just do nothing?

Comment: i found right now another post from our forum with an answers about the same issue, (i did not check them out yet), you can try them on <https://askubuntu.com/questions/60044/how-do-i-change-the-font-dpi-settings>

Comment: John, this was what I was looking for. Can you promote your comment to an answer so I can mark it? I used dconf-editor which solved the issue.

Comment: hi there @Christine i added the link to my exist answer, glad that helped you out.