# How do I use strftime to customize the default date-time format?

Tags: time, indicator, date

The date on my computer currently displays as "Fri Feb 24" and the System Settings give no options for changing the date format.

I need the date to display as "Fri 24 Feb" followed by 24-hour-time.

Could someone help me out to configure "Fri 24 Feb" and then the time in 24-hour? Is there a way to get this time & date format to be default EVERYWHERE in Ubuntu (e.g., in Terminal & Nautilus)?

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/44025/652. Answer there gives more information about creating your own format, rather than choosing from a standard list.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the date/time, select "time and date settings", on the second (Clock) tab you can configure 24-hour time.

As for the day/date/month order, that's locale-dependent, for instance, I have en_CA "English (Canada)" and I see 'Fri 24 Feb'. Go to system settings, Language Support, and on the second (regional) tab you can select a locale that better matches what you want. If you select "apply system-wide" this should also affect Nautilus and (well-behaved) command-line utilities; I haven't tried this last part though, so no promises :)