# How to show current timezone near time indicator in the menu bar?

Tags: unity, indicator, time, date, timezone

How to show the current timezone near time and date in the menu bar in Ubuntu 16.10? This should be relevant for the other versions also.
It is a very missing feature, you can easily be confused without it.
I would like to get something like "Fri Dec 23 20:35:05 (Europe/Kiev)".

Also it would be nice to be able to customize that string arbitrarily, say "Friday, 23.12.2016 - 20:35:05 (Europe/Kiev)". Thank you!

**Update**

Referring to [How to change the date format?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43999/how-to-change-the-date-format)
one can do

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format "'custom'"`

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime custom-time-format "'%a, %d.%m.%y - %H:%M:%S (%Z)'"`

which changes the system time and date indicator to

> Friday, 23.12.2016 - 20:35:05 (EET)

As you can see, everything is fine now, besides the timezone name. I set my timezones at *Time & Date settings > Clock > Choose Locations*. Then, if I write
`timedatectl` in terminal I get

> Time zone: Europe/Kiev (EET, +0200)

So, there are several options for a timezone name and it seems that it is *strftime* function that decides which one to use and also that just by feeding it with a format string there is no way to get a timezone name "Europe/Kiev" (only "EET" or "+0200").

So are there any ways to choose a timezone's name format?

Maybe using Serg's script I could place the preferred name next to the system indicator?

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible with default indicator, as far as i know, but I can make a separate indicator that displays just the time zone

Answer (score 5):

#### Introduction

The indicator presented below displays current timezone in the top panel. The way it works is fairly simple. Timezone settings are set in `/etc/timezone` file. All the indicator does, is read that file, and update the information displayed if necessary.

Save the source code below as `~/bin/timezone_indicator` , run `chmod +x ~/bin/timezone_indicator` to make it executable, and run as `~/bin/timezone_indicator`. If you wish for it to start each time you log in automatically, open Startup Applications menu, and add the full path to the indicator as one of the commands there.

[image]

Feel free to test changing the timezone as show in https://askubuntu.com/a/524362/295286

#### Script Source

Also available on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/5ba3690b8e368832f270449deb290783):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
# Author: Serg Kolo , <1047481448@qq.com>
# Date: December 23, 2016
# Purpose: Indicator that displays timezone
# Written for:  https://askubuntu.com/q/863952/295286
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
#
# Licensed under The MIT License (MIT).
# See included LICENSE file or the notice below.
#
# Copyright © 2016 Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
# in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.
import gi
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import GLib as glib
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from time import gmtime
import os

class TimezoneIndicator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = appindicator.Indicator.new(
            'timezone-ndicator', "",
            appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)

        self.app.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
        self.app.set_icon('locale')

        self.app_menu = gtk.Menu()
        self.quit_app = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        self.quit_app.connect('activate', self.quit)
        self.quit_app.show()

        self.cache = None

        self.app_menu.append(self.quit_app)
        self.app.set_menu(self.app_menu)

        self.update_label()

    def run(self):
        gtk.main()

    def quit(self, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def update_label(self):
        timezone = None
        with open('/etc/timezone') as f: 
             timezone = f.read().strip()
        if timezone != self.cache:
             self.app.set_label(timezone,"")
        self.cache = timezone
        glib.timeout_add_seconds(1, self.callback)

    def callback(self):
        self.update_label()

def main():

    indicator = TimezoneIndicator()
    indicator.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Всегда пожалуста, земляк ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, works great and solved my need perfectly! Next step is to make a PPA for this!

Answer (score 1):

If you can obtain the timezone in a format you're happy with from a terminal command, you could then install [Sysmonitor Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/38000/67335) and add that command (as a script).

You could go further and disable the default clock (there's an option to hide it).  Your script/command would then display the date/time/timezone to your liking.

Comment: This isn't a practical solution, it just gives a script *after* you click on it. It doesn't display the output/return of the script in the indicator.

Comment: I linked to the wrong indicator; hopefully fixed.

Comment: Much better answer now! Now what would make the answer better is an example to use with that indicator. Especially one that runs every X seconds if there is a chance of it replacing the system installed time indicator.

Comment: I have since added background script functionality to https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335 which would allow you to display the timezone (once obtained via a terminal command and santised).