# Widget or taskbar indicator to show my IP + IP Geo Location

Tags: networking, gui, indicator, ip

Is there a widget or taskbar indicator that is always on top to show me my IP and Geo IP location? I need to know if I'm connected to my VPN at all time or not.

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 17. I think its called gnome?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a special package for that, please check out https://github.com/icamys/locindicator

Comment: I will try it :)

Comment: I like it. I would like to help with some ideas. Can I send a PR from time to time?

Comment: @Chemah Sure, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write a script or one-liner terminal command to obtain your IP and/or Geo IP location, then refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865606/67335) and swap in your code.